# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "На основании изложенного (,) прошу Вашего разрешения продлить лечение гражданина Иванова А.Б. в ЦРБ."

Answer (score 2):

Не нужна. Оборот не слишком распространенный (не слишком длинный).

Comment: А длинный - это какой?

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна, даже интуитивно.